# How to use JDate / HTMLHelper inside model?

Tags: model, jdate, timezone, htmlhelper

So I have this component (built with JCB) where I need to display a saved datetime from the db (without seconds, but that's not my focus right now). Because of some limitations, I cannot simply declare `use` statements at the top of the model.

I'm now at the point that I called the `JDate` like so:

```
$date = new Joomla\CMS\Date\Date($item->kickoff);
$datenow = new JDate($item->kickoff);
$dateHtml =  '';
echo '<pre>' . var_export($item->kickoff,true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . var_export($date,true) . '</pre>';
$item->calculated_name =  $dateHtml;
```

The export gives me:

```
'2020-07-30 12:00:00'

Joomla\CMS\Date\Date::__set_state(array(
   'tz' => DateTimeZone::__set_state(array(
       'timezone_type' => 2,
       'timezone' => 'GMT',
   )),
   'date' => '2020-07-30 12:00:00.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 2,
   'timezone' => 'GMT',
))
```

I should now be able to use the information from the export, but I cannot. I cannot access `$date->date` or `$date->get('date')` because it's in set state.

I'm not able to use `HtmlHelper` because I cannot use it like so:

```
$dateHtml = new Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper($date, Text::_('DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATETIME'));
```

My goal: Access the kickoff date calculated with the offset (Joomla installation timezone)

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Joomla\CMS\Date\Date` doesn't have `$date` property or `get()` method. Use `$date->format($format)` to format the date where `$format` is the date format.

To format a date using `Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper`, call its underscore method with `date` as first argument, followed by date and format:

```
Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper::_('date', $item->kickoff, $format);
```